# Pandas .iloc indexing coupled with boolean indexing in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

I looked into existing threads regarding indexing, none of said threads address the present use case.

I would like to alter specific values in a `DataFrame` based on their position therein, ie., I'd like the values in the second column from the first to the 4th row to be `NaN` and values in the third column, first and second row to be `NaN` say we have the following `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.standard_normal((7,3)))
print(df)
          0         1         2
0 -1.102888  1.293658 -2.290175
1 -1.826924 -0.661667 -1.067578
2  1.015479  0.058240 -0.228613
3 -0.760368  0.256324 -0.259946
4  0.496348  0.437496  0.646149
5  0.717212  0.481687 -2.640917
6 -0.141584 -1.997986  1.226350
```

And I want alter `df` like below with the least amount of code:

```
          0         1         2
0 -1.102888       NaN       NaN
1 -1.826924       NaN       NaN
2  1.015479       NaN -0.228613
3 -0.760368       NaN -0.259946
4  0.496348  0.437496  0.646149
5  0.717212  0.481687 -2.640917
6 -0.141584 -1.997986  1.226350
```

I tried using boolean indexing with `.loc` but resulted in an error:

```
df.loc[(:2,1:) & (2:4,1)] = np.nan

# exception message:
df.loc[(:2,1:) & (2:4,1)] = np.nan
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also thought about converting the `DataFrame` object to a numpy `narray` object but then I wouldn't know how to use boolean in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is define the requirement and assign to be clear:

```
d = {1:4,2:2}
for col,val in d.items():
    df.iloc[:val,col] = np.nan
```

---

```
print(df)
```

---

```
          0         1         2
0 -1.102888       NaN       NaN
1 -1.826924       NaN       NaN
2  1.015479       NaN -0.228613
3 -0.760368       NaN -0.259946
4  0.496348  0.437496  0.646149
5  0.717212  0.481687 -2.640917
6 -0.141584 -1.997986  1.226350
```

Comment: Thank you @anky , if I do understand correctly, there is no way to use the boolean `&` so as to set values to `np.nan` within `.loc` or `.iloc` functions using one line of code?

Comment: @MehdiRH There might be , however it might be non readable. Not sure. You can wait to find out if you receive your desired answer. This was one working example

Comment: It might also make sense to keep the slices as slices for a more generalised solution that wouldn't rely on slicing the same direction each time (like with `:val`). Something like `for idx in (pd.IndexSlice[:2, 1:], pd.IndexSlice[2:4, 1]): df.loc[idx] = np.nan`

Comment: @HenryEcker Thanks. Nice to see the diamond against your name!